# ESAPI - Validator() | Canonicalize

Tags: java, xss, esapi

I am trying to use ESAPI validator to address reflect cross side scripting problem. I tried to use ESAPI validator on the API Post request as below

```
try {
            String document_number = ESAPI.validator()
                    .getValidInput("Doc Number",qReq.getDocument_number(),
                            "SafeString",15,false,true);
            valid = true;   
        } catch (IntrusionException e) {
            LOGGER.info("Intrusion Exception");
            LOGGER.error("Error Message for User --> " + e.getMessage());
            LOGGER.error("Error Message for User --> " + e.getLogMessage());
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            LOGGER.info("Validation Exception");
            LOGGER.error("Error Message for User --> " + e.getMessage());
            LOGGER.error("Error Message for User --> " + e.getLogMessage());
    }
```

I have enabled **canonicalize** to true, as per the last parameter in the **getValidInput** function, but somehow it doesn't do that?

My input request would be

> {
>         "document_date": "2017-09-18",
>         "tran_type":null,"document_number":"%68%74%74%70%3a%2f" }

And i expect output

> {
>         "document_date": "2017-09-18",
>         "tran_type":null,"document_number":"http:/" }

Any thoughts would be helpful?

Regards,
Sunil

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting?

Comment: When I tried your test case, you're getting rejected because you set the length to 15 and the string is much bigger than that.

Comment: @avgvstvs Yep i cleared the error, sorry for the delayed reply